# How to create an array of datatypes/structs in C

Tags: c

You can create an array of functions in C like this:

```
(*funcs[3]) = {
  fna,
  fnb
};
```

Wondering if you can do the same sort of thing but for datatypes or structs.

When I do:

```
struct foo[3] = {void, int, char};
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: expected identifier or '('
  struct foo[3] = {void, int, char};
```

The goal would be I'm trying to dynamically get the data type from an array for `va_list` and `va_arg`:

```
va_arg(my_va_list, foo[1]);
```

Wondering if anything like this is possible.

This is similar to the idea of returning a datatype from a function. Something like:

```
type
return_integer_type() {
  return int;
}
```

If *that's* possible too, that would be interesting to know, but not the original question.

Comment: Types are not values, you can't assign or return them.

Comment: An alternative to "get the data type from an array for va_list and va_arg" is to pass to the `bar(....)` function data that specifics the type - automatically as with [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Comment: C doesn't provide any introspection method to find out data types, and C data doesn't have latent type information. It requires you to tell it what the type is with declarations.

Comment: The closest you could get is a `union`, but that is typically not advisable.

Comment: @abelenky would be interested to see that.

Answer (score -2):

I think this insight might me able to help you:

```
static STRUCTURE_NAME *STRUCTURE_OBJECT_NAME[NUMBER_OF_STRUCTURE_OBJECTS];
```

For example:

```
struct foo
 {
   int x;
 };
static foo *fooo[3];
```